# disappearing data in flutter on page change

Tags: api, flutter, flutter-layout

I started the flutter app to learn API functions but I am getting this problem that is when I change the page and go back to the previous page the data that I was displaying becomes null on all the pages. and I don't know the reason behind this.

below is the image of how it goes -:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]

below is the code in which I am getting data from one page to the home page and I am displaying it.
and it disappears on page change -:

```
import 'package:education/LogIn_SignUp/Log_In.dart';
import 'package:education/Screens/Profile_Screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'About_Scree.dart';
import 'Change_Password.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';






class homeView extends StatefulWidget{

  var user_id;
  var user_name;
  var mobile_number;
  var user_address;
  var user_Email;
  var coaching_id;
  var coaching_name;
  var coaching_address;
  var primary_no;
  var altnumber;
  var coaching_email;



  homeView({
    this.user_id,this.user_name,this.mobile_number,this.user_address,this.coaching_id,this.coaching_name,
    this.coaching_address,this.primary_no,this.altnumber,this.coaching_email,this.user_Email
});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => homeViewState();
}



class homeViewState extends State<homeView> {


  TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();

  var showItemList = List<String>();
  int count = 10;




  var userid, username, mobilenumber, useraddress, userEmail, coachingid, coachingname, coachingaddress;
  var primaryno, alt_number, coachingemail;

  void setdata(){
    setState(() {
      userid = widget.user_id;
      username = widget.user_name;
      mobilenumber = widget.mobile_number;
      useraddress = widget.user_address;
      userEmail = widget.user_Email;
      coachingid = widget.coaching_id;
      coachingname = widget.coaching_name;
      coachingaddress = widget.coaching_address;
    });
  }



  @override
  void initState(){
    // showItemList.addAll(initList);
    // getData();
    setdata();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    editingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  /// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ///                                           Main Build Function for the class.
  /// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(90.0),
          child: AppBar(
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              child: Text(
                '$coachingname',//'${widget.coaching_name}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  letterSpacing: 4.5,
                  fontFamily: 'Sarif',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
            centerTitle: true,
            actions: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    child: new IconButton(
                        icon: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                          child: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                        ),
                        onPressed:(){
                          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
                          ));
                        }
                    ),
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => LoginPage()
                      ));
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[

                Container(
                  height: 180,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                      Colors.purple.shade300,
                      Colors.deepPurpleAccent.shade200,
                    ]),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [

                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45.0, bottom: 10),
                        child: Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(55),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: Icon(Icons.perm_identity_outlined, color: Colors.white,size: 30),
                            )
                        ),
                      ),

                      Text(
                        '$username',//'${widget.user_name}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24,
                          letterSpacing: 2.5,
                        ),
                      ),


                    ],
                  ),
                ),


                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Profile',
                    style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 17,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    letterSpacing: 1.5,
                  ),
                  ),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.person_pin, color: Colors.blue,),
                  selectedTileColor: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ProfilePage(
                        user_id: userid, user_name:username, mobile_number:mobilenumber, user_address:useraddress,
                        user_Email: userEmail,
                      )
                    ));
                  },
                ),

                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Change Password',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      letterSpacing: 1.5,
                    ),
                  ),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.security, color: Colors.blue,),
                  selectedTileColor: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ChangePassword()
                    ));
                  },
                ),

                ListTile(
                  title: Text('About',
                    style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 17,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    letterSpacing: 1.5,
                  ),
                ),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.info_outline, color: Colors.blue,),
                  selectedTileColor: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => AboutScreen(
                        coaching_id:coachingid, coaching_name:coachingname, coaching_address:coachingaddress,
                        primary_no:primaryno, altnumber:alt_number, coaching_email:coachingemail
                      )//coaching details
                    ));
                  },
                ),

                ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'Rate',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      letterSpacing: 1.5,
                    ),
                  ),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.star_border_outlined, color: Colors.blue,),
                  selectedTileColor: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: (){

                  },
                ),


                Divider(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  thickness: 1,
                ),


                SizedBox(height: 10,),

                Text(
                  'Contact Us',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.grey[800],
                    letterSpacing: 1.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(height: 10,),

                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Share',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      letterSpacing: 1.5,
                    ),
                  ),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.share, color: Colors.blue,),
                  selectedTileColor: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: (){

                  },
                ),

                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Privacy Policy',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      letterSpacing: 1.5,
                    ),
                  ),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.privacy_tip, color: Colors.blue,),
                  selectedTileColor: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: (){

                  },
                ),

                ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'LogOut',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      letterSpacing: 1.5,
                    ),
                  ),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.logout, color: Colors.blue,),
                  selectedTileColor: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => LoginPage()
                    ));

                  },
                ),



              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the data that I am passing to this page is as below -:

```
I/flutter ( 4512): {address: jaipur, jaipur, alt_number: 9865358577, coach_address: Gautam Budha nagar, noida, coach_id: 2, coach_name: SSG Coaching, coaching_email: SSG@gmail.com, mobile_number: 9999999999, primary_no: 9898557898, res: success, user_id: 3, user_mail: s@gmail.com, user_name: sagar, user_pass: sagar123}
```

please help as I am unable to trace the error or find any solution.

Comment: means you want to suppose you go from MainPage to homeView page then data is showing but when you go from homeView to another page and return back to another page then data is not showing right ?

Comment: yes whenever i change page the data disappears

Comment: Yes because you are sending data from only one page through constructor. So this data disapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using Navigator.pushReplacement instead of Navigator.push. When you use pushReplacement, the current route gets overridden by the new route.

So use this:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ProfilePage(
                        user_id: userid, user_name:username, mobile_number:mobilenumber, user_address:useraddress,
                        user_Email: userEmail,
                      )
                    ));
```

And inside the ProfilePage, use

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

To go back to the homeView

Answer (score 2):

that's is really normal because your data isn't stored in persistent storage like SQL lite, shared preferences, etc. And you shouldn't save anything not crucial into persistent local storage, because it's too expensive for your app size. There is something more that is state management with state management you wouldn't require to store your data in persistent storage, instead of store your data in a temporary so-called "semi-persistent" state. if you want to learn more about managing your data without doing async activity like crazy, you can follow these steps below.

first is to pass the data using vanilla Navigator push, and class constructor (depends on your routes type "named or not ClassNamed type of routes")
like the one @dshukertjr mentioned

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => ProfilePage(user_id: userid, user_name:username, mobile_number:mobilenumber, user_address:useraddress,user_Email: userEmail,)
));
```

or using named route instead

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, PackageWeight.routeName, arguments: Your data here);
```

learn here about named routes :
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes

- Pros: This is just simple af,
- cons: you can't passing your data to the entire apps with this only, because this isn't good enough for managing the state for a lot of widgets.

two is to save the current data locally using provider/state management learn here about state management.
hint: you can use the provider package, it's really simple just add some map class to parse the data
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

- Pros: This is really neat for managing a state for a lot of widgets.
- Cons: sometimes it's overkill to use provider & consumer to do a simple task like saving button save etc
- Personal advice: Learn this, you wouldn't regret it, because you can use this almost everywhere & every situation in a flutter to managing state and data (semi persistently).

Comment: thank you so much for this info I will read it